# PostGis geospatial query slower than a customized python script

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I 'm pretty new in PostGis and I'm using it in order to perform geospatial query but it seems quite slow in returning the desired results.

Before I used a python script that usually returns the results in  in more or less 5 seconds (searching over 1.2M of elements).

In order to get this result in a faster way I moved the problem on postgis, but, as I just write before, it takes more then 20 seconds for the same job.

More precisely each element is made by a point (lat lon) and a string (label for the point)

I'm using a dockerized postgis (https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis) on my I7 16 gb ram (ubuntu 18.04)

I created the db in the following way:

```
CREATE DATABASE demo;
\c demo
create extension postgis;
CREATE TABLE mypoints ( id serial primary key, name varchar(50), the_geom geometry(POINT,4326) );
```

and inserted the points (1,2M), by means of a python script, in this way

```
INSERT INTO cities (the_geom, name) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-3.782 40.4351)',4326), 'point_label');
```

The query I used is:

```
select name from cities where ST_Distance_Sphere(the_geom,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-3.713 40.4321)',4326))<500;
```

Am I doing something wrong?
How is it possible that my python code is faster than an query optimized on geospatial problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking full advantage of PostGis because you're not yet using spatial indexes.

To create an index in your table:

```
create index my_index_points_gist on mypoints using gist(the_geom);
```

Then run `cluster` and `analyze` on your table:

```
cluster mypoints using my_index_points_gist;
analyze mypoints;
```

I see that your using spherical distance, it would be better if you use geography type then:

```
CREATE TABLE mypoints ( id serial primary key, name varchar(50), geog geography );
```

Insert data in the usual way, adding a cast to geograhy type:

```
INSERT INTO cities (geog, name) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-3.782 40.4351)',4326)::geography, 'point_label');
```

Alternatively, just add an extra geography colum:

```
alter table mypoints add column geog::geography;
update table mypoints set geog = the_geom::geography;
```

create index but using geog this time

```
create index my_index_points_gist_geog on mypoints using gist(geog);
cluster mypoints using my_index_points_gist_geog;
analyze mypoints;
```

And for the query you can then use:

```
select name from cities
where ST_Distance(geog,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-3.713 40.4321)',4326)::geog)<500;
```

Or even better:

```
select name from cities
where ST_DWITHIN(geog,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-3.713 40.4321)',4326)::geog,500);
```

For reference:
[postgis geography type](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html)